# Pytorch: multiplication between parameters is inplace for LBFGS optimizer?

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation, in-place

I am trying to solve a kind of inverse problem by backward propagation with pytorch. I am trying to recover the parameters (r, theta) that generate a vector field U(r,theta).
As I intended to use the LBFGS optimizer from pytorch, I realize that the operation

**r*theta**

is detected as inplace and thus not supported for the backward computation of the gradient, whereas

**r+theta** is not.

How can I overcome this ? I actually need to recover fields that use transformations of the form r*theta.

Here is an example of a code that reproduces the error: it is running fine if you change

```
field = Wrong_U_param(r, theta, positions)
```

by

```
field =  U_param(r, theta, positions)
```

in the loop. Is also works if you replace the r*theta operation by r.item()*theta (but is does not optimize over r since there is no more gradient depending on r.
I tried to use torch.mul() to run the product but it also fails.

The error message is the following

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation
```

and the automatic detection points towards this very product.

Thank you for your help !

```
import numpy as np
import torch
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
import torch.optim as optim
from geomloss import SamplesLoss
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)


def model(field):
    return field

def U_param(r, theta, pos):
    result = r + theta + 0. * pos
    return result

def Wrong_U_param(r, theta, pos):
    result = r * theta + 0. * pos
    return result

def learn_U_param(Zobs, ngrad, params, r_guess=0., theta_guess=0., lambd=1.):
Npts = params[0]

positions = torch.tensor(np.arange(0, 1, 1 / Npts) + 1 / 2 / Npts).reshape((Npts, 1))
    lab = torch.tensor(np.arange(0, Npts))

    r = torch.tensor(float(r_guess)).to(device)
    r.requires_grad = True
    theta = torch.tensor(float(theta_guess)).to(device)
    theta.requires_grad = True
    r_hist = [r.item()]
    theta_hist = [theta.item()]
    loss_hist = []

    optimizer = optim.LBFGS([r, theta])

    for i in range(ngrad):
        field = Wrong_U_param(r, theta, positions)
        Z = model(field)
        Loss = SamplesLoss(loss="sinkhorn", p=2, blur=.05)
        Wass = Loss(lab, Z, positions, lab, Zobs, positions)


        def closure():
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            Wass.backward(retain_graph=True)
            return Wass

        optimizer.step(closure)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        r_hist.append(r.item())
        theta_hist.append(theta.item())
        loss_hist.append(Wass.item())

    return r_hist, theta_hist, loss_hist
N=100
r = 2
theta = 2
params = [N]
positions = torch.tensor(np.arange(0, 1, 1 / N) + 1 / 2 / N).reshape((N, 1))
Zobs = U_param(r, theta, positions)
ngrad = 10
print(learn_U_param(Zobs, ngrad, params, r_guess=0.1, theta_guess=0.1, lambd=1.))
```

Comment: First of all, are you confusing "inline" with "inplace"? And why need you need to retain the graph? Neither `U_param` nor `Wrong_U_param` is inplace. The problem could be in some other op. As to why using multiplication or addition makes a difference, I believe it is because addition does not require storing the operands for gradients while multiplication does.

Comment: Hello ihdv, thank you for your attention.
I get this runtime error
`RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling .backward() or autograd.grad() the first time.`
if I do not retain the graph

Yes you are right I had this terminology confusion, I corrected it.

Actually, the problem should not be in U_param or Wrong_U_param, but since the second one is raising an error and the detector points towards it, I really think the problem is in the multiplication ...

Comment: @FrancisLand how did you get past this error? I am having the same issue